# Where is the source for this Material 2 example sheet?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

https://material2-dev.firebaseapp.com/card
All of these examples are quite thorough and indepth offering many different ways to do what i want to do with the Angular 2 Material 2 components.
I just cant find where its sourced to properly understand how they did it
Is the source code hosted somewhere I can access? such as github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [Angular Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples). I realize the example(s) there aren't the exact same as the ones on the site, those look based off of what is in the [AngularJS Material Docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/card)... the format is very similar and it shouldn't be very difficult to replicate them from those two resources. Hope that helps!

Comment: The answer is invalid. The material2-dev app is different from the official example in the Angular material docs.

Comment: The answer is certainly valid. It's exactly how I solved the question and, judging from it being accepted by the poster, how he was able to solve it as well.

Comment: These examples are different from whats in the Material docs. They have more examples and sometimes, this is the only place that demonstrates specific material features. It's not the material docs, it's its own repo, as I pointed out in my answer - https://material2-dev.firebaseapp.com/card

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, regardless it helped me figure out what the poster was asking and appeared to help him as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's the material demo app, the sources for that app are in the material repo:

https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/dev-app

And you can find a discussion about it here:

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/438